# Bash script that acts like makefile

Tags: bash

I want to make a bash script that works like a makefile.
It would have the options like -archive, -clean, -backup and etc.
The only requirement is that it must have the -o argument so it specifies a name.
The problem I have right now is that I don't know how to pull out the .c files from the arguments.

For example, if I inputed 
./compile.sh -o name -backup hello_world.c print.c

How would I compile this?

Here's the code I have so far.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

if [ $1 != '-o' ]; then
echo "ERROR -o wasn't present as first argument"
echo "HELP"
echo "BASH syntax: $ compile –o filename –clean –backup –archive -help cfilenames"
echo "WHERE:"
echo "$             Unix Prompt"
echo "comiple       Name of bash program"
echo "-o filename   Mandatory Argument"
echo "-clean        Optional and when present deletes all .o files"
echo "-backup       Optional and copies all .c and .h files into backup directory"
echo "-archive      Optional and Tars content of source directory. Then moved to backup directory"
echo "-help     Provides list of commands"
echo "cfilenames    Name of files to be compiled together"
fi
NAME=$2
shift
shift

options=$@
arguments=($options)

index=0
for argument in $options
do
    index=`expr $index + 1`
    case $argument in
      -clean) echo "clean" ;;
      -backup) echo "backup"
        mv -f *.c ~/backup
        mv -f *.c ~/backup ;;
      -archive) echo "archive"
        tar -zcvf backup.tar.gz *
        mv -f backup.tar.gz ~/backup/backup.tar.gz
        ;;
      -help) echo "help"
                echo "HELP"
                echo "BASH syntax: $ compile –o filename –clean –backup –archive -help cfilenames"
                echo "WHERE:"
                echo "$             Unix Prompt"
                echo "comiple       Name of bash program"
                echo "-o filename   Mandatory Argument"
                echo "-clean        Optional and when present deletes all .o files"
                echo "-backup       Optional and copies all .c and .h files into backup directory"
                echo "-archive      Optional and Tars content of source directory. Then moved to backup directory"
                echo "-help         Provides list of commands"
                echo "cfilenames    Name of files to be compiled together"
        ;;
esac
done
exit;
```

Thanks

Comment: I wanted to try something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to be looking for [getopts(1P)](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-getopts-116), a bash built-in for parsing options.  You use it as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
while getopts "abc:" flag do
    echo "$flag" $OPTIND $OPTARG
done
```

Read more: http://aplawrence.com/Unix/getopts.html#ixzz1qAQ29TFW

If you'd like to use long options, you can use [getopt(1)](ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/), a separate program that you can invoke from bash.  It is part of `linux-util`, which is part of the default install for most distros, or at least part of the base packages.

Comment: I was originally using getopts but I read that you can not use long arguments with it.

Comment: Since it's a separate program, does that mean it isn't universal? I wouldn't be able to transfer it to another machine for example.